# PHP - cURL To Array?

Tags: php, curl

How could I use cURL to get back an array from this URL? http://module.game-monitor.com/67.202.102.136:27016/data/server.php

This is my code so far.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://module.game-monitor.com/67.202.102.136:27016/data/server.php'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false); // remove body 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  
$head = curl_exec($ch); 
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
curl_close($ch); 
$head = unserialize($head);
$head = objectToArray($head);
$head["query_time"] = str_ireplace('ms', '', $head["query_time"]);
return $head;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just use [PHP Type Casting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting) `(array)` and remove the `objectToArray` function

```
$head = unserialize($head);
$head = (array) $head ;
var_dump($head);
```

Output

```
array
  'ip' => string '67.202.102.136' (length=14)
  'port' => string '27016' (length=5)
  'player' => int 0
  'maxplayer' => int 14
  'name' => string 'Another www.cogameservers.com CSGO Server' (length=41)
  'premium' => string '0' (length=1)
  'link' => string 'http://www.game-monitor.com/csgo2_GameServer/67.202.102.136:27016/Another_www.cogameservers.com_CSGO_Server.html' (length=112)
  'error' => int 0
  'query_time' => string '0ms' (length=3)
```

Comment: When i paste the content of the webpage in a file and I run the linux command `file` to get infos, I get `Solitaire Image Recorder format`. Never seen this before. Anyone having more infos of the data representation of the string ? It's serialized in which format ?

Comment: Yes Baba, but how did you know to use `unserialize()` on this strange string ?

Comment: I did not save it just treated it has a `string` @sputnick